# Apex Sharing : AccountShare ImplicitParent

Tags: public-group, apex-sharing

I am querying below AccountShare records -

```
Select Id,AccountAccessLevel,Account.Name,RowCause,UserOrGroupId from AccountShare where UserOrGroupId='some_id'
```

I am getting 2 records in which AccountAccessLevel = Read and RowCause = ImplicitParent.

Still, I am able to edit the Account, I have checked all the sharing settings.

Can't find the cause.

Comment: There are tons of routes to record-level access. Per your last question, you're using View All permission. Are you also using Modify All or Modify All Data?

Comment: I removed View All on the all the permission sets and Profile before testing it. No user only had View All.